# Implementation of aggregator pattern in Java

Tags: java, design-patterns, aggregate

**[edit]** Hmm, clearly I'm not asking this properly. Could you tell me why this is a bad question?

To put this differently, I want to find a why to implement what is define in [this article](http://cowboyprogramming.com/2007/01/05/evolve-your-heirachy/) as "Pure object aggregation" instead of "Object organized as a blob".

I'm doing my first attempt at implementing the aggregation pattern in Java.

At first glance Interfaces seems to be the answer, I ran into confusion when I needed default values for attributes.
Since constants are static, if I define anything in the interface it will be shared with every class that implements it. What I was going for was that I only need to implement this in cases when I wanted a value different from default.

Here an abstract class seems a better fit but I fall back to a multiple inheritance problem.

Here is the (impossible) skeleton I can up with:

```
public interface MenuItemPopup {
    // Defaults
    int windowHeight = 200;
    int windowWidth = 350;

    public void open();

    public void setWindowHeight(int newHeight){
        windowHeight = newHeight;
    }

    public void setWindowWidth(int newWidth){
        windowWidth = newWidth;
    }

}

public interface WindowButton {
    // Defaults
    Point size = new Point (5, 120);

    public void initialize();

    public void setSize(Point newSize){
        size = newSize;
    }
}

public class SomeFuncGUI extends MandatoryParentClass implements WindowButton, MenuItemPopup{

    public void open(){
        // do stuff
    }

    public void initialize(){
        // do more stuff
    }
}

public class OtherFuncGUI extends MandatoryParentClass implements MenuItemPopup{

    public OtherFuncGUI(Point customPosition){
        setSize(new Point(45, 92));
    }

    public void open(){
        // do stuff
    }
}

public class MainClass{
    ArrayList <MandatoryParentClass> list = new ArrayList <MandatoryParentClass>();
    list.add(new SomeFuncGUI());
    list.add(new OtherFuncGUI());

    for( MandatoryParentClass button : list){
        // process buttons
        if(button instanceof WindowButton){
            button.open();
        }
        // process popups
        if(button instanceof MenuItemPopup){
            button.initialize();
        }
    }
}
```

I realise this doesn't compile.
How would I change this to implement aggregation pattern for MenuItemPopup and WindowButton?

Comment: the answer here is to not use inheritence. there is no need to inherit windowButton, instead make it a concrete class and have a field of the type

Comment: The reason for the downvotes is that this is off-topic here. Implementation questions belong on StackOverflow. Programmers is for conceptual/design type questions. Please take a moment to read the site's [FAQ] to familiarize yourself with how this site works.

Comment: Very sorry, I was wondering about that. Should have read the FAQ. Will move post.

Comment: @kotoko ideally instead of reposting, one would allow those with the ability to migrate it (it isn't an instant process).